# Sphere with different capacities

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure

I want to create a graphic representation. I have a sphere with radius of 50. I need to create two different filled capacities when it is one-fourth and three-fourths of its total capacity.

What I already have is this:

```
[x,y,z] = sphere();
r = 50;
surf( r*x, r*y, r*z ) % sphere with radius 50 centred at (0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create the spere in two parts. Take a look at the following example:

```
% First part -- 0 to pi/2    
theta = linspace(0,pi/2);
phi = linspace(-pi/2,pi/2);
[theta, phi] = meshgrid(theta, phi);
rho = 50;
[x, y, z] = sph2cart(theta, phi, rho);
surf(x,y,z, 'EdgeColor', 'b');

% Second part -- 90 to 360
hold on;
theta = linspace(pi/2,2*pi);
[theta, phi] = meshgrid(theta, phi);
[x, y, z] = sph2cart(theta, phi, rho);
surf(x,y,z, 'EdgeColor', 'r');
hold off;
```

It produces a graph like the following.
[image: Sphere]